# Не выводится текст на страничке в Node js. Почему и как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Не выводится текст, почему версия 15.

**index.html**

```
<div class="right_part">
    <input class="search" placeholder="Поиск"></input>
    <i id="menu_open" class="fa fa-bars menu_open" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="clear_both"></div>



    {{#if article}}
        {{#each article}}
            <div class="news_container">
                <div class="news_block">
                    <div class="news_title">{{ article.title }}</div>
                    <div class="news_text">{{article.small_text}}<span class="news_more_text">... ещё</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
    <h1> НЕт статей</h1>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

**todos.js**

```
router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    const article = new Article({
        title: req.body.title,
        text: req.body.text,
        small_text: req.body.small_text,
    })

    await article.save()

    res.redirect('/')
})
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mangoose = require('mongoose')
const path = require('path')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const todoRoutes = require('./routes/todos')


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs'
})

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', 'views')

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use(todoRoutes)



async function start() {
    try {
        await mangoose.connect('mongodb+srv://nikita:1v2v3v4v5v@cluster0.kfgvz.mongodb.net/todos', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
        })
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('Server has been started...')
        })
    } catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

[image: вот там где находится курсор должен выводиться текс]

Comment: Какой шаблонизатор вы используете?

Comment: @Voprositel handlebars, скорее всего

Comment: я использую node js

Comment: Если вы **НЕ** используете никакой шаблонизатор, то текст и не будет выводиться

Comment: какой шаблонизатор вы имеете ввиду

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/219873/